# Redirect own WAN traffic to LAN

Tags: router, internet, modem, traffic

Let's say my WAN IP is `123.456.789.0`

Earlier, when I connected to `123.456.789.0:22` from the LAN, my traffic reached my LAN correctly and the service worked fine. It also worked fine when I connected from the WAN.

Recently, I switched to a new TP-Link Archer C5 2.0 router. This router doesn't have a built-in modem like my old one, so an additional modem is added.

Now, connecting from the WAN works as usual, but connecting from the LAN fails (it is unable to create a connection). My use case in connecting to my WAN IP from LAN is avoiding changing sessions from SFTP utilities like WinSCP.

I haven't tested if having a separate router and modem might be the cause of this, since issue still persists when I bypass my router and try sending traffic to my own WAN IP without the router in the middle.

I assume that either of these is the issue here:

1. There is some inherent issue with sending packets to your own IP (this seems unlikely), and my old router redirected such packets on its own, which the new router doesn't.
2. There is no issue with sending packets to your own IP via the WAN, and my old router worked fine while the new one doesn't.

Is there just some configuration option on my router which I'm missing?

Comment: Which device does your WAN IP address belong to? The TP-Link Archer, or the additional modem?

Comment: The modem. The TP-Link Archer is just a router and doesn't have an IP of its own (afaik).

Comment: No, you have it backwards. Routers _always_ have an IP address; modems don't necessarily need to (although still usually have one, but only for configuration/management purposes).

Comment: Good to know. In my case, I still think it is the modem since my WAN IP remains the same even when I replace the router with my laptop (the modem has only 1 output).

Comment: That doesn't mean much. It would be just as normal if the ISP assigned the same address to any device you connect, whether it's a router or a laptop. How do you determine what "your" WAN IP _is_? You need to look at the address shown by the device itself (e.g. the laptop's network status), not at what's shown by some website.

Comment: I just checked my router - it shows the same IP that google shows when I search for "my ip". Is this what you wanted?

Comment: When you connect to your WAN address, are you expecting to reach the router itself, or a device within the LAN? It sounds like you have configured a port-forwarding rule on the Archer?

Comment: A device within the LAN. I've forwarded the port on my router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you're missing the "NAT loopback" (aka "NAT hairpin") configuration option.

---

> There is some inherent issue with sending packets to your own IP (this seems unlikely), and my old router redirected such packets on its own, which the new router doesn't.

Yes, there is. But you're forgetting that "sending packets to your own IP" isn't the *only* thing that happens.

Your WAN IP address doesn't belong to the whole LAN at once – it belongs to your *router* only, and other devices in your LAN wouldn't even recognize that address if they saw it on a packet header. They only recognize *their own* LAN addresses (e.g. the typical 192.168.x.y).

This means that connections to the WAN IP address *always* go to the router, which then needs to rewrite the packets' destination address and re-send the updated packet to the final device. Naturally, responses *from* that device need the opposite rewriting to be done (i.e. changing the *source* address back from the device's own LAN IP to the router's WAN IP).

But if the server recognizes that its client is in the same subnet, it will send responses *directly*, not via the router, and the router won't have any chance to un-translate the source IP address. As a result, your client computer sends packets to the WAN address, but receives replies from the LAN address, and is unable to match the two.

Some routers have a "NAT loopback" feature which rewrites both the destintion *and* source of such packets. The downside is that your server will only see the router's, not the actual client's, IP address. (Additionally, the performance might be limited by the router's CPU.)

Comment: Perfect! This also explains the slight slowdown I experienced when doing this with my old modem+router.